# How to add a css and cfm files to index.cfm

Tags: css, coldfusion

I am having a hard time to figure out how to add a css file and a cfm file to a cfm file. I am new to coldfusion and I have tried the following but when I render the page, it appears blank. The same goes for the cfm file, nothing appears and I followed an example online. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/medstyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>
<cfoutput>
    <cfinclude template="net/net2_header.cfm">  
</cfoutput>
blah
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: right sorry I posted it before realize it and I have made the changes but it still does not work correctly. The page is blank minus the blah word. It is just not rendering the header for some reason

Comment: @RobertoFlores Could you add `net2_header.cfm` to ur question? I suspect that might have some issues.

Comment: Right now your code looks valid as we see it. There's probably an error in the included template. If you can't post it here, you can try wrapping everything in `cftry` and `cfcatch` tags and dumping that for a workable error message.

Comment: take away the cfoutput block and see if the word, `blah`, appears.

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things.

First change the index.cfm file to:

```
<html>
<body>
<cfoutput>
Is coldfusion running: #iif(1 eq 1,"""yes""","")#
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Browse to the page and check if the output is: Is coldfusion running: yes

If this is the case coldfusion is running and there are no problems here.
Now try the following. Change the index.cfm file to:

```
<html>
<body>
<Cftry>
    <cfinclude template="net/net2_header.cfm">  
    <cfcatch type="any">An error occurred</cfcatch>
</Cftry>
</body>
</html>
```

and change the net/net2_header.cfm file to:

```
Hello world
```

Browse to the index.cfm page and check if the output is: Hello world. If so change net/net2_header.cfm file back to your original code and browse the page again. If an error occurs post the error message. If nothing occurs post the content of the net/net2_header.cfm file.